# Accord du pronom attribut

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, accord, attributs

Le Bon Usage énonce la règle de l'accord du pronom attribut à la § 673 (14ième édition).

- *Pour représenter soit un nom précédé de l'article défini ou d'un
  déterminant démonstratif, possessif ou interrogatif, soit un
  nom propre sans déterminant, la langue écrite emploie comme
  pronoms attributs le, la, les, en accord avec ce nom :

  ○ Vous dites : nous ne sommes pas la révolution. Eh bien, soyons-LA (MALRAUX, Espoir, p. 8)

  ○ J'ai été cette pauvre chose-là. Tu LA seras toi aussi (MONTHERL., Solstice de juin, p. 256)*

Plus loin dans la section viennent les précisions suivantes.

- *La langue parlée n'observe guère cette syntaxe. […]
  Dans la langue écrite même, on met parfois le neutre le (au lieu du
  pronom en accord avec le nom) :

  ○ Que de naïves bourgeoises soient les dupes de vos faussetés ; moi, je ne LE serai
  jamais [dit la duchesse] (BALZAC, Duch. de Langeais, Pl., p. 193).

  ○  Vos sujets ? Ils ne LE sont plus (R. ROLLAND, Léonides, II, 3).

  ○ — Aërt. Vous n'êtes pas ma
  mère. / Lia. Il me semble que je LE suis, en vous entendant parler (ID., Tragédie
  de la foi, Aërt, p. 43).*

Ce manque à la règle se trouve même dans la langue parlée; j'ai pu le constater  assez régulièrement. Les  questions sont celles-ci.
1/ Dans la langue parlée, quel est le registre de langue reconnu pour cet usage ? Trop littéraire ? Courant ? Informel ? Incorrect ?
2/ Quel nom porte cet usage ? Par exemple, dans une copie d'examen quelle explication donne-t-on dans l'analyse grammaticale qui est demandée de ce pronom ? Est-il suffisant de spécifier que c'est le pronom de genre neutre ?

Exemple : « LE » dans la dernière citation
LE -- pronom personnel ; 3ième personne du singulier; genre : neutre ; antécédent: mère, féminin singulier, attribut du sujet « je »,…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 1/ Dans la langue parlée, quel est le registre de langue reconnu pour cet usage ? Trop littéraire ? Courant ? Informel ? Incorrect ?

Si tu parles de l'accord, je dirais que c'est un usage très littéraire. L'absence d'accord se rencontre dans tous les registres. Je doute que grand monde fasse cet accord spontanément et souvent, une autre construction est choisie pour le contourner.

Par exemple:

> *Cette femme, je **la** suis !* → Toujours évité, au moins à l'oral à cause de la collision avec le verbe *suivre*, sauf par plaisanterie ou excès de zèle, bien sûr.

> *Cette femme, je **le** suis !* → Se rencontre, mais rarement.

> *Cette femme, c'est moi !* → Largement le plus courant.

> *(Les) champions du monde, nous **les** serons !* → Jamais entendu.

> *(Les) champions du monde, nous **le** serons !* → Courant, littéraire.

> *(Les) champions du monde, on le sera !* → Courant, parlé.

- 2/ Quel nom porte cet usage ? Par exemple, dans une copie d'examen quelle explication donne-t-on dans l'analyse grammaticale qui est demandée de ce pronom ? Est-il suffisant de spécifier que c'est le pronom de genre neutre ?

Probablement. Il s'agit bien d'un usage neutre, comme si le pronom n'était pas attribut du déterminant en question (ici: *cette femme*, *les champions du monde*) mais renvoyait aux propositions *être cette femme* et *être champions du monde*)